Conjugacy classes of normal subgroup in group
Let $G$ be a finite group, and $N$ be a normal subgroup of index $p$.
If every conjugacy class of $N$ is also a conjugacy class in $G$, what can we say about $G$ or $N$?
Such instances occur if $G$ is abelian, or more generally, if there is some $x\in G\setminus N$ which centralizes $N$. But beside these two situations, I was not able to find any example of group $G$ and $N$ with $[G:N]=p$ and every conjugacy class of $N$ is a conjugacy class of $G$.

You need every element of $N$ to have centralizer not contained in $N$. There are examples in which $C_G(N)$ is
contained in $N$. A computer search shows that the smallest such example has order $64$ with $N$ of index $2$. The group is $\mathtt{SmallGroup}(64,257)$.

Sorry; if $|G|=64$ and if $N\trianglelefteq G$ has index $2$ whose centralizer in $G$ is outside $N$, then this will imply that $N$ is centralized by some $x\in G\setminus N$. (I was looking examples other than this situation - as mentioned in question.)

In the  example I am describing we have $C_G(N) \le N$ (in fact $C_G(N) = Z(G)$ has order $2$), but $C_G(n) \not\le N$ for all $n \in N$. This final condition is equivalent to all of the conjugacy classes in $N$ being equal to classes in $G$. I could give a presentation of the group and define $N$ if that would be helpful, but it might be easier for you to check it yourself in GAP or Magma.
